# Make selected text in Word document bulleted (recording doesn't work)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel VBA script that generates a Word doc.  Some of the generated text in that word doc needs to be listed as a bulleted list (i, ii, iii, iv...).  I have gotten as far as highlighting the desired text, which I have succeeded in applying other text effects to, but I cannot get the bulleted list to work.  I have tried recording a Word macro for making a bullet list - this macro works on selected text in Word but does not work when I try to apply it in my Excel VBA script.

The following script selects the desired text and makes it Bold.  I want it to make the selected text a bullet list using i, ii, iii style bullets instead.

```
Set rngStart Order.Bookmarks("violations").Range Set rngEnd = _
Order.Bookmarks("violationsEnd").Range Order.Range(rngStart.Start, _
rngEnd.End).Select Order.Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Bold = True
```

Thank you for whatever help you can offer.  Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got your selected text in a Range object, you can apply bulleted list format like this:

```
Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

Comment: Thank you!  Substituting "ApplyOutlineNumberDefault" got me exactly the result I wanted.